# How to grep with alternation

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I would like to grep lines which include a comma followed by four identical digits followed by a comma followed by an alphabetic character.

I tried

```
grep -E ,'1111|2222|3333|4444|5555|6666|7777|8888|9999',[[:alpha:]] file
```

This doesn't seem to do what I describe.  The problem is that it doesn't handle the commas and [[:alpha:]] properly it seems.

How can you do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because your alternation is not applied in the way you are expecting. To make it behave as you want, you need to use groups:

```
grep -E ,'(1111)|(2222)|(3333)|(4444)|(5555)|(6666)|(7777)|(8888)|(9999)',[[:alpha:]] file
```

Alternatively, this could be expressed more succinctly using a backref:

```
grep -E ,'([[:digit:]])\1{3},[[:alpha:]]' file
```

which basically means the same digit 4 times. This also includes 0, however, so it may or may not help you.

EDIT:

Of course... to make it only 1-9, you could

```
grep -E ,'([1-9])\1{3},[[:alpha:]]' file
```

Comment: Thank you. The options you give are very slow unfortunately. Is there a way to speed them up?

Comment: @Anush: What's the scale of the file? MB? GB? How long is it taking?

Comment: About 1GB.  It is much slower than the other answer.

Comment: Could be the backref. Other than that it's not obvious to me why it should be so much slower, but regex can be a funny thing in terms of tuning them for efficiency. Do you see it only with the backref or with both? I'd be curious to know.

Answer (score 2):

try this for you regex

```
',(1111|2222|3333|4444|5555|6666|7777|8888|9999|0000),\w'
```

Comment: It should be [[:alpha:]] but apart from that this the fastest solution. Thank you.